# STRUTS 2 CON JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, java, json, struts, struts2

Hola estimados voy 2 semanas con la siguiente consulta :

Tengo el siguiente script :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function report() {     
    $.getJSON("listanotificacion.action", function(data) {

        var tblBalance = "";


        $.each(data.listanotificacion, function() {                 

            tblBalance += this.balance;

            });

        $("#tbody3").html(tblBalance);


    });
}
```

El  script me lanza un valor que puede ser "0" si no se ha realizado ningún registro o en caso contrario la cantidad de registros que se han realizado, ese valor lo asigno ah tblBalance tal y como se muestra aqui :

```
<span class="notification" id="tbody3">  <a id="tblBalance" /> </a>  </span>
              <p class="d-lg-none d-md-block">
                Some Actions
              </p>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, lo que quise hacer despues era mostrar un mensaje al usuario que si el valor "tdBalance" es 0 poner un mensaje de "No tiene registros pendientes por crear", en caso contrario mostrar el mensaje de "tiene registros pendientes por crear", como estoy trabajando con struts2 pense hacerlo de la siguiente manera :

```
<s:set var="ws" value="%{#tbody3.tblBalance}"  /><s:if test="%{#ws==0}" > <a class="dropdown-item"  onclick="demo.showSwal('error')"> El balance aun no esta realizado  </a>  
 </s:if> <s:else>
 <a class="dropdown-item"  onclick="demo.showSwal('listo')"> Tu Balance ya esta listo!   </a>  </s:else>
```

Mi pregunta es como asigno un valor dado por javascript a una etiqueta struts2?, he intentado con el property y nada!! alguna solucion ? le estaria muy agradecido.

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De la manera que estás tratando de hacerlo (con lo que estoy entendiendo) me temo que no lo vas a conseguir. Piensa que el renderizado de la página JSP ocurre antes de que se empiece a ejecutar el código Javascript. Por lo que no puedes utilizar una etiqueta de JSP con un dato de JavaScript ya que ese dato no existe aún, ni los datos están en las mismas máquinas (el código JSP lo está ejecutando el servidor, el código JavaScript lo está ejecutando el cliente).

Tienes varias maneras de resolverlo: Realmente parece que tienes de elementos `a` y se muestran si tienes balance o si no tienes de forma excluyente. Puedes tener uno de los dos oculto, y cuando tengas la respuesta JSON del servidor, mostrar uno y ocutar el otro.

```
<a id="nolisto" class="dropdown-item" onclick="demo.showSwal('error')">El balance aun no esta realizado</a>
<a id="listo" style="display: none;" class="dropdown-item" onclick="demo.showSwal('listo')"> Tu Balance ya esta listo!</a>
```

En el JS:

```
function report() {     
    $.getJSON("listanotificacion.action", function(data) {
       // [...] Aquí tu código anterior
       if (tblBalance === 0) { // O LA CONDICIÓN QUE NECESISTES VERIFICAR
          $("#listo").hide();
          $("#nolisto").show();
       } else {
          $("#listo").show();
          $("#nolisto").hide();
       }
    });
}
```

Para algo más complicado ya te recomendaría que te metieras con algún framework como angular o vue si tu proyecto te lo permite.